# How do I include all .cpp and header files in this situation?

Tags: c++

So, say I have something like this:

main.cpp

```
#include "main.h"

int main() {
    displayMessage();
    return 0;
 }
```

main.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
```

display.cpp

```
#include "display.h"

void displayMessage() {
    std::cout << "HELLO!\n";
}
```

display.h

```
void displayMessage();
```

How could I include all of them together without being deeply nested? I just started programming a week ago and trying to start early before college starts this upcoming Fall.

Comment: Or, let's say, what's the more "professional" way they would do it in the real world?

Comment: Compile each `.cpp` file separately to make an `.o` (object) file and then link the two resulting object files to make an executable. What compiler are you using?

Comment: The GNU GCG Compiler?

Answer (score 1):

First giving main a header just to include its headers is a little over the top so I would avoid that.

Something like this:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

#include "display.h"

int main() {
    displayMessage();
    return 0;
 }
```

**display.cpp**

```
#include "display.h"

void displayMessage() {
    std::cout << "HELLO!\n";
}
```

**display.h**

```
// prevent including the same header twice
#ifndef MY_PROJECT_DISPLAY_H
#define MY_PROJECT_DISPLAY_H

void displayMessage();

#endif // MY_PROJECT_DISPLAY_H
```

Then compile each `.cpp` file to an object file:

```
g++ -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -c -o display.o display.cpp
```

Then link the objects to make an executable:

```
g++ -o my_program_name main.o display.o
```

You may want to set some useful flags while compiling (highly recommended):

```
g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -c -o display.o display.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better if you don't create and include `main.h` in `main.cpp`. Instead include `display.h` in `main.cpp`.

Also "Modern C++" encourages to use C++ style include headers `<cstdio>` instead of C style ones `stdio.h`.

And yes, welcome to programming. It's fun. :)

Comment: So move everything into one header file instead of multiple header files?

Comment: No. First lets understand why do we need header files. Header files only say the interface of functions and data structures. They don't have any implementation details. For example we have a header file **music.h** having a function **void play_music()** but it does not say how to play music. Now we add this implementation of how to play music in a separate file **music.cpp**. Now we can include **music.h**, in the file having **main** function (also called a client) to call the play_music function. In this way you can create multiple headers/implementation files for different functionalities.